# Vim using wrong colors

Tags: vim, colors, color-scheme, gnome-terminal

I have a problem with my vim and terminal configurations.
I am on Fedora Linux 27, run i3 and the gnome-terminal. I want to use the `srcery` color scheme [(GH page)](https://github.com/roosta/vim-srcery). On GVim it works perfectly, right out the box. However, on the terminal it doesn't look as good. Srcery isn't the only color scheme with this issue, virtually all Base16 color schemes and all others that use 256 colors suffer from the same problem.

What I find bizarre, is that my `$TERM` variable is set to `xterm-256color`, `tput colors` gives out 256, and even vim itself claims to have a `t_Co` set to 256. I can do things like make the background of vim transparent, which then works properly.

[image: Here] you can see the color scheme working properly in GVim
[image: And here] a comparison to normal vim.

I have my `gnome-terminal` colors set to the srcery colors as well, there's a script on the GH page to create a `srcery` profile, which i am using. Alas, that does not help with my issue either.

Currently, I don't know how i could enable vim to correctly display my color scheme
Any help you could provide would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `set termguicolors`?

Comment: @glhrmv yes, that does not improve it. it makes most of my text white, and some (like vim's `set` keyword) become light blue